# python: getting all pairs of values from list

Tags: python

I'd like a tuple of each pair of values from a list, e.g.

`[1,2,3,4]`

Would yield:

```
(1,2)
(1,3)
(1,4)
(2,3)
(2,4)
(3,4)
```

This seems very one-line recipe ish but I can't quite get it to work.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That is actually the combinations of 2 elements from your list. Use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) this way:

```
>>> your_list = [1,2,3,4]
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> list(combinations(your_list,2))
# [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)]
```

If you need *all* pairs, use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

Or, you can use simple list-comprehension:

```
>>> your_list = [1,2,3,4]
>>> [(your_list[i], your_list[j]) for i in range(len(your_list)) for j in range(i+1,len(your_list))]
# [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid accessing list element using indices, a more Pythonic way is the following:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4]

listOfPairs = []
for e1 in lst:
    for e2 in lst:
        if e1 >= e2: continue #Flip sign for descending order
        listOfPairs.append((e1, e2))
```

Say you can't use the `<` `<=` `>` `>=` comparators on the elements of the list, eg in a list of functions, you can <s>call the .index() function</s> **use the indices from the `enumerate()` function** (sorting according to list order):

```
#Some nonsense example functions
def f1(): return
def f2(): return
def f3(): return
def f4(): return

lst = [f1, f2, f3, f4]

listOfPairs2 = []
for i1, e1 in enumerate(lst):
    for i2, e2 in enumerate(lst):
        if i1 >= i2: continue
        listOfPairs2.append((e1, e2))
```

Comment: Using `list.index` like that inside the loop actually gives your algorithm a cubic complexity. This is much, much slower. I suggest using `for ii, e1 in enumerate(lst):` instead, and then refer to `i1` rather than the terribly inefficient `lst.index(e1)`.

Comment: @Stef you are correct. I was not aware they run a full blown linear search for this function and expected some optimizations under the hood (like implicitly running an enumerate when doing a for loop and then extracting the index value from that). 

So I agree, my for loops should both have enumerate, and then use indices from there.